# iOS: Size classes and device orientation at launch

Tags: ios, swift, device-orientation

Here is my problem: rotate an iPhone 6 Plus or an iPad to e.g. `LandscapeLeft`.

Lets say your app has the following code (only for example)

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait 
    // mine does use All, but with this case you'll understand my question
}
```

How do I detect if the device should use vertical or horizontal layout when

```
func willTransitionToTraitCollection(newCollection: UITraitCollection, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
```

is called?

```
print(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width < UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
// will return false, because we started in landscape but the layout will be forced to be vertical here

print(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation == .LandscapeLeft)
// will return true, because we started in landscape but the layout will be forced to be vertical here
```

The main problem appears on the iPad, because both size classes are `regular`.

I'm confused and have no idea how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think of your layouts as vertical and horizontal. Just let the app rotate, and respond to the size class or the size change.

On the iPad, try to avoid having two layouts. Just use autolayout to rejigger the proportions automatically. But if you *must* respond to rotation on the iPad, then respond to `viewWillTransitionToSize` (because the trait collection won't change).

Comment: I'm trying to build a custom mechanism which will apply horizontal or vertical constraints automatically. Just resizing the views is not an option because I want be able to build two different layouts if needed. This way a vertical layout can be totally different from horizontal layout.

Comment: Understood. But the answer to that is in my answer. Watch `viewWillTransitionToSize` and compare width to height to decide what's happening.

Comment: Here's an actual example you can download and experiment with: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p257rotationChangesInterface4iPad/ch19p593rotationChangesInterface/ViewController.swift Shows how to swap out layouts based on rotation on the iPad.

Comment: Yeah, still struggling how to build a good dynamic mechanism that will respond to everything as needed. :) The example is a bit similar to my current mechanism I already build, but its not perfect at its state right now. ... Btw. the trait collection may change on the new iPads when you will resize your app while using the new multitasking.

Comment: "the trait collection may change on the new iPads when you will resize your app while using the new multitasking" Correct, but that isn't what you asked about. I'm just trying to explain what to do about responding to rotation on the iPad. By the way, if you think there aren't enough size classes, welcome to the club.